# Async arrow functions return type

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I am trying to use async arrow function as a callback for another function. Here the value returning from the arrow function has no significance, so I am not returning anything. But, since i am using it as async function do I need to return a value or Promise.resolve("somevalue") from the arrow function.

When I tested the below code without returning any value it worked, but i am not sure whether its the correct way.

```
const ack = async (result) => {
  await this.service.updateObject(result);
} // No return is given
```

The method ack is called a callback to another function.

Comment: You don't need to do anything, by default an `async` function returns a promise resolving to undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you're doing currently is just fine. `async` functions automatically return Promises which resolve to whatever is `return`ed from the function. If nothing is returned explicitly, then the Promise resolves to `undefined`, just like calling a function that doesn't return anything results in `undefined` being returned.

So if you just need the function to *do* something, but you don't need a possible result to be used by the consumer of the function, feel free to use `await` inside the function without returning anything. This is a common pattern.